# Confidence Interval for large dataset

Tags: matplotlib, statistics, regression, seaborn, confidence-interval

I would like to get a confidence interval for very large datasets. It is composed by around 700,000 points for x and y. I also tried to use less data, like 200 points, and with that it is possible to plot. But, when it comes to my specific datasets, it does not show the confidence interval.

For that, my code is based on:

```py
x_x = np.array(y_test[:, 0]) #about 700,000 points
y_y = np.array(y_pred[:, 0]) #about 700,000 points

sns.set(style = 'whitegrid')

p = sns.FacetGrid(d, size = 4, aspect = 1.5) 
p.map(plt.scatter, 'x_x', 'y_y', color = 'red')
p.map(sns.regplot, 'x_x', 'y_y', scatter = False, ci = 95, 
    fit_reg = True, color = 'blue') 
p.map(sns.regplot, 'x_x', 'y_y', scatter = False, ci = 0, 
    fit_reg = True, color = 'darkgreen')
```

And also the Figure so far:
[image]

Comment: Confidence intervals shrink with the number of datapoints. With 700K points, they will likely be so small as to be invisible on a plot. (However, if you do not have 700K *independent* observations, this will be an underestimate of the actual uncertainty).

Comment: Thank for your answer, in this case is there a suitable statistical analysis to be applied?

Comment: what are you trying to show with the CI? as long as you use a linear regression, the error of your prediction is inversely proportional to the number of samples, https://onlinestatbook.com/2/regression/accuracy.html